# Akka classic: how do I spawn a child actor from an AbstractActor?

Tags: akka, akka-actor

I'm reading [Akka's documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/guide/tutorial_1.html) for typed actors, which describes how to spawn child actors.

However, I don't find a way to achieve the same using a classic AbstractActor.

I am confused about whether it is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current Akka documentation refers to actors based on `AbstractActor` as "classic" actors.

Here's the documentation for classic actors:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/index-classic.html

What you're looking for is here:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#creating-actors-with-props

> Using the ActorSystem will create top-level actors, supervised by the actor system’s provided guardian actor while using an actor’s context will create a child actor.